# Pivot with datediff

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How would I remove the zeros and replace them with null values considering they are really not a zero value?

My working data

```
id       class     startdate      enddate    
 1        High        1/1/15       2/1/15      
 1         Low        5/1/15       6/1/15      
 1         Mid        6/1/15      6/10/15 
 2     Mid-low        6/1/15      6/10/15
```

My query below

```
 select y.id, y.startdate, y.enddate, ISNULL(y.High,'') AS HIGH, ISNULL(y.MID,'') AS MID, ISNULL(y.LOW,'') AS LOW, ISNULL(y.Mid-low,'') AS Mid-low, 
from
(
select id, class, datediff(day, startDate, endDate) as days
from @test
) x
pivot
(
max(days) for class in (high, low, med)
) y
```

This returns the set value below

```
  id     High       Mid    low    Mid-low
   1       30         9     30          0
   2        0         0      0         30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having to post this as an answer to show code.   I am unable to reproduce OP's results.

This code:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
  ColA char(1)
 ,ColB int
 );

 INSERT INTO @Table(ColA,ColB) VALUES ('A',NULL);

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ColA,ColB
FROM @Table
)x
PIVOT (
SUM(ColB) FOR ColA IN (A,B)  --same result if SUM() is changed to MAX()
) y;
```

Results in:

```
A     B
NULL  NULL
```

So OP is definitely doing something more than his example illustrates to be getting zeros in his/her results.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`NULLIF()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function:

> NULLIF returns the first expression if the two expressions are not equal. If the expressions are equal, NULLIF returns a null value of the type of the first expression.

```
select id,NULLIF(high,0) AS high,NULLIF(med,0) AS med,NULLIF(low,0) AS low
from
(
select id, class, datediff(day, startDate, endDate) as days
from @test
) x
pivot
(
max(days) for class in (high, low, med)
) y
```

Comment: However, be aware that NULLIF() won't discriminate between numbers that are actually zero, and numbers that were NULLs that summed to Zero.   All Zeroes will be displayed as NULL.

Comment: @TabAlleman  Right and I have cases where zero is actually zero. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @TabAlleman I must be missing something here... where is this summing going on? I see no `SUM()` in his PIVOT query, only `MAX()`.

Comment: Well, I assumed his example isn't his real query, because MAX() of NULL is NULL, not 0.   So if he's getting zeros, he must be doing some summing or something else in his real query.

Comment: @MrJohn All I can do is answer the question that is given to me. If there is context that isn't supplied in the question, I can't take that into account. If you want a suitable answer, provide **all** context that pertains to your question **inside** the question.

Comment: My apologies. I am using a ISNULL function and I have updated my question. I now realize I need to remove the ISNULL function and that resolves my issue.